# When adding navigation property in addition to a foreign key integer property Entity Framework is creating two Id fields in my table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Following the [Entity Framework Core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) I created the following entity:

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

When running `Update-Database` I end up with `BlogId` and `BlogId1` columns. I don't remember running into this issue in the past. Isn't it recommended to add a foreign key integer option to allow for more querying options?

Is there any possible way for this to work where there is just a single `BlogId` column in SQL and when I retrieve data both the `BlogId` and `Blog.Id` are populated with it?

Comment: Ending up with such duplicate columns is a clear indication of improper relationship fluent configuration. Hence the answer lies somewhere in your model configuration not shown here.

Comment: @IvanStoev Do I need any additional data annotations or fluent configuration or is this model setup good enough where by default entity framework should do the correct thing?

Comment: By default EF should do the correct thing. No data annotations / fluent config is needed. My suspect is that you *do* have some fluent code which leaves some navigation property out of the relationship, thus forcing EF Core to create second relationship (and associated FK). It usually happens when you omit navigation property accessor in `HasMany` / `HasOne` / `WithMany` / `WithOne`.